# Tkinter - Python, how do I cause a button click to assign a value to a variable?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Using Tkinter and Python. Already created a window for the buttons to be placed on. I want there to be four buttons to appear, and I want to be able to click one of the four buttons, and be able for it to set the selection variable = "whatever I clicked", so that I can then use this variable later to call an API. When I run the program and click on the "General knowledge" button and print the selection, it does correctly print "General knowledge", but then when I try to return this selection variable it just doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
def select1():
    selection = "General Knowledge"
    print(selection)

def select2():
    selection = "Science"

def select3():
    selection = "Entertainment"

def select4():
    selection = "Miscellaneous"



button1 = tk.Button(text = "General Knowledge", command = select1)
button1.place(x=100, y=100)

button2 = tk.Button(text = "Science", command = select2)    
button2.place(x=100, y=140)

button3 = tk.Button(text = "Entertainment", command = select3)
button3.place(x=100, y=180)

button4 = tk.Button(text = "Miscellaneous", command = select4)
button4.place(x=100, y=220)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish your goal.

One way is to write a single function that will take a value to assign to your variable. This way you can have as many buttons as you like and only a single function.

Not if you are using functions you have to either pass the variable to the function or let the function know it is in the global namespace.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
selection = ''


def assign_value(value):
    global selection
    selection = value
    lbl["text"] = value
    print(selection)


lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Selection Goes Here')
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(text="General Knowledge", command=lambda: assign_value("General Knowledge")).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Science", command=lambda: assign_value("Science")).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Entertainment", command=lambda: assign_value("Entertainment")).grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Miscellaneous", command=lambda: assign_value("Miscellaneous")).grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can assign the value directly from the button.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
selection = tk.StringVar()
selection.set('Selection Goes Here')


lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=selection)
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(text="General Knowledge", command=lambda: selection.set("General Knowledge")).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Science", command=lambda: selection.set("Science")).grid(row=2, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Entertainment", command=lambda: selection.set("Entertainment")).grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Button(text="Miscellaneous", command=lambda: selection.set("Miscellaneous")).grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I am sure if I spent more time on this I could think up something else but the idea is basically write your code in a more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) fashion and make sure you are assigning the value to the variable in the global namespace or else it will not work as you expect.